# change image on translateanimation on android

Tags: android

I implement the translateAnimation to a imageview.

it Successfully animatated.

One translate is moving up and another one is moving down. i need to change image when start second translate.

My code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
android:shareInterpolator="true">
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%p"
    android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="20%"
    android:drawable="@drawable/bs_bunny1"
    android:duration="2000" android:startOffset="100"/>
<translate 

    android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%p"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="-20%p"
    android:duration="3000" android:startOffset="100"/></set>
```

I set the above animation to the imageview.

But i want to chage the image when start to load the second translate.. How to do it.

Comment: moving up and moving down will work at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to break it up into two animations, and register a Animation.AnimationListener to the first translate animation. On Animation.AnimationListener's onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) callback, do the image change and then start the second animation, like thus:

```
translate.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    view.setImageResource(resId);
    view.startAnimation(translate2);
}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
}
});
```